# why User is being kicked out from docusign ui with in 4-5 seconds

Tags: docusignapi

I have embedded docusign ui in my app.its working fine in lower environments.But user is being kick out from docusign ui within 4-5 seconds in docusign production.I know there is session timeout configuration ,it is configured 20 minutes.Anyone have faced this issue..any suggestion/help is appreciated

**Retrieve docusign embedded url**

```
public async Task<EmbeddedSigningUrls> BuildEmbeddedDocSigningUrlAsync(


      string signerName, string signerEmail,
        string redirectAfterSigningBaseUrl,
        string envelopeId)
    {
        var viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
        {
            ReturnUrl =
                $"{redirectAfterSigningBaseUrl}?{RedirectUriBuilderParser.SigningOperationIdQueryParamName}={envelopeId}",
            ClientUserId = signerEmail,
            AuthenticationMethod = "password", // <<== not "email"
            UserName = signerName,
            Email = signerEmail                
        };

        var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

        var recipientView = await envelopesApi.CreateRecipientViewAsync(await AccountAsync(), envelopeId,
            viewOptions);
        return new EmbeddedSigningUrls
        {
            EmbeddedSigningUri = new Uri(recipientView.Url)
        };
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "kicked out"? you mean to say that after 4 seconds the UI doing something even if the user was just reading the document?

Comment: are you using embedded signing? can you share your code/APIs?

Comment: yes, I am using embedded signing.its embedded in iframe.even if user is filling out form ,its kickout and redirect to url redirecturl(which was being set at the time of envelope creation).its happening in prod docusign account.I cant reproduce in demo account.

Comment: added source code..This is happening 2 times out of 10 in production account.

Comment: can you try to change authenticationMethod from "password" to "none" and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: can you please explain what will happen internally for "none"?

Comment: since you embed the UI inside your app, there's no additional need for DocuSign to authenticate the user. It is done in your API calls. you will get back a URL that will eventually expire, but not within seconds

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code to this:

```
var viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
        {
            ReturnUrl =
                $"{redirectAfterSigningBaseUrl}?{RedirectUriBuilderParser.SigningOperationIdQueryParamName}={envelopeId}",
            ClientUserId = signerEmail,
            AuthenticationMethod = "none", // <<== not "email"
            UserName = signerName,
            Email = signerEmail                
        };
```

As your appliaction is just embedding a URL for the signing and is not adding additional authentication layer beyond the API calls that it is making.

Comment: by this..do docusign session will timeout after given time like I have configured it to 20 minutes?

Comment: the timeout is fixed as far as I know and cannot be configured. I believe it's 5 min

Comment: there is a config section in admin login where user can define session timeout time in minutes..

Comment: that timeout is only for using the web app, not for your integration code when you use embedded signing/sending.